# How to resolve dependency conflict while installing Bootstrap using Angular CLI command?

Tags: angular, dependencies, angular-cli, ng-bootstrap, conflict

I tried to install Bootstrap in my Angular application by using the CLI command:
ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap. But I got the following errors in return.
How to resolve these dependency conflict while installing Bootstrap using Angular CLI command?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JNco.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The problem

Your problem is due to an upstream peer dependency version conflict where @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@12.1.2 (upstream) has a peer dependency of @angular/common@^13.0.0 (downstream). Please research [Peer Dependencies](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/)

Also check [@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap dependencies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap#dependencies)

You have a number of options:

### Option 1 - Ignore the peer dependency version (at your peril)

Install using `--legacy-peer-deps` switch to "...accept a potentially broken dependency resolution." (as per the error message). This will mean that the package developer of `@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@12.1.2` will/should have tested this with `@angular/common@^13.0.0`.

```
npm install @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap --legacy-peer-deps
```

### Option 2 - Downgrade your Angular project to a compatible version (13)

Either install Angular v13 globally `npm install -g @angular/cli@13.n.n` and create new project `ng new project` or if you have already created a project you could adjust the  versions in `package.json` accordingly and `npm install` or use [npx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52331625/how-to-create-a-specific-version-of-angular-project-using-cli)

Also check this [Fix the upstream dependency conflict while installing ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71188820/fix-the-upstream-dependency-conflict-while-installing-ng-bootstrap-ng-bootstrap)