# angular-highcharts unable to resolve dependency tree peer @angular/common@"^13.0.0" from angular-highcharts@14.1.5

Tags: angular, highcharts, npm-install, angular-highcharts, dependency-tree

Trying to install angular-highcharts to my angular project but I m getting the error below:

```
PS C:\Users\YUNUS\Desktop\newProject\gos-panel\src\app\shared> npm i angular-highcharts highcharts
```

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: gos-panel@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@14.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^13.0.0" from angular-highcharts@14.1.5
npm ERR! node_modules/angular-highcharts
npm ERR!   angular-highcharts@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\YUNUS\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\YUNUS\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-07-25T13_43_51_090Z-debug-0.log

Comment: Answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72575853/how-to-resolve-dependency-conflict-while-installing-bootstrap-using-angular-cli/72576028#72576028

Comment: downgrade `angular-highcharts` version to support your `Angular` version. https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-highcharts/v/13.0.1

Comment: Recommend using the official package [Highcharts angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-angular) and [wrapper](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular), it's better documented and fully supported.

Answer (score 0):

You can check peer dependencies for `angular-highcharts` as below.

```
npm info angular-highcharts peerDependencies
```

Result:

```
 '@angular/common': '^13.0.0', '@angular/core': '^13.0.0' }
```

Note that `angular-highcharts` requires `@angular/common` and `@angular/core` version 13.n.n.

You are using version `@angular/common@14.1.0` it appears.

Please either install Angular 13 or work around the issue by using the command:

```
npm i angular-highcharts highcharts --legacy-peer-deps
```

As per the error above though, this peer dependency hasn't necessarily been tested.

> Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.