# Conflict between the dependencies @angular/common and @ng-idle/core

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, version-control, dependencies

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @ng-idle/core@2.0.0-beta.15
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@7.2.16
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^7.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0 || ^9.0.0" from @agm/core@1.0.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@agm/core
npm ERR!     @agm/core@"1.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   6 more (@angular/forms, @angular/platform-browser, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0" from @ng-idle/core@2.0.0-beta.15
npm ERR! node_modules/@ng-idle/core
npm ERR!   @ng-idle/core@"^2.0.0-beta.15" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @ng-idle/core@"^2.0.0-beta.15" from @ng-idle/keepalive@2.0.0-beta.15
npm ERR!   node_modules/@ng-idle/keepalive
npm ERR!     @ng-idle/keepalive@"^2.0.0-beta.15" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/common@5.2.11
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0" from @ng-idle/core@2.0.0-beta.15
npm ERR!   node_modules/@ng-idle/core
npm ERR!     @ng-idle/core@"^2.0.0-beta.15" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @ng-idle/core@"^2.0.0-beta.15" from @ng-idle/keepalive@2.0.0-beta.15
npm ERR!     node_modules/@ng-idle/keepalive
npm ERR!       @ng-idle/keepalive@"^2.0.0-beta.15" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\objec\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-06-14T07_17_12_068Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\objec\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-06-14T07_17_12_068Z-debug-0.log

I'm first time in Angular. I couldn't run npm install. It showing my @ng-idle/core not supported to my angular, how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

This is an NPM peer dependency issue. In summary, a peer dependency is where an installed NPM package relies on a host project containing a specific version of an installation of a package further downstream.

Your version of `@ng-idle/core@"^2.0.0-beta.15` relies upon certain [NPM Peer Dependancies](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies).

To find what these are you can use the command as below.

```
npm info @ng-idle/core@2.0.0-beta.15 peerDependencies
```

Result:

```
{
  '@angular/common': '^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0',
  '@angular/core': '^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0'
}
```

As you will see from the above result, your package is expecting `@angular/common` between v4 and v5.

You can ignore this message with the `--legacy-peer-deps` switch but obviously the version will probably not have been tested with other versions, which is why you get the error:

```
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Alternatively, try installing a compatible version of your package. For example you could try latest version.

Test before with:

```
npm info @ng-idle/core peerDependencies
```

Resulting in an versions greater than or equal to v9.

```
{ '@angular/common': '>=9.0.0', '@angular/core': '>=9.0.0' }
```

Install latest verion as follows:

```
npm install @ng-idle/core@latest
```

There is also a useful [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/check-peer-dependencies) you can use in a project to check for peer dependencies via `npx`.

```
npx check-peer-dependencies
```

Also this explains further: [angular/compiler-cli peer dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73945429/angular-compiler-cli-peer-dependencies/73945992#73945992)