# I'm having an error when running my project-npm error

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular version 15.2.8 however I'm getting errors when I to run my project.

Attached is some screenshots.
Please help
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/or9pw.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhWJn.png)

I want the npm to work because I need to run my project, I tried updating the angular version

Comment: Add all information as text not as image

Answer (score 0):

As requested above, if you could update your question with text rather than screen dumps.

That said, having looked at your screen dumps, you are experiencing "peer dependency" issues.

https://indepth.dev/posts/1187/npm-peer-dependencies

This is documented in one of my earlier replies.

[Conflict between the dependencies @angular/common and @ng-idle/core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76471122/conflict-between-the-dependencies-angular-common-and-ng-idle-core/76472338#76472338)